# Firebase: Data structuring query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie to firebase and need some suggestions on structuring data. 
I am designing a database for an application where multiple people may share a bank account and can update the status of this account. The group of people sharing this account may also keep changing. So, multiple people may perform actions which will influence the balance available in an account. I decided to list the linked accounts under each user so that one pull is enough to get a list of all user accounts once user logs in. If user is interested in details of a specific account (like balance) then I will go and fetch that child from accounts sub-tree. It all seems fine until I think about notifying users in a smartphone app if the balance associated with any of their linked account changes. Since the balance attribute is not under any specific "user" sub-tree, how to monitor for this change at the application level. 
I don't want to bring balance attribute under "user" sub-tree or else I will have to find the duplicate copies and update all of them whenever balance of an account changes. Moreover this approach will not scale well.
Any suggestion?

[image: Sample DB Snapshot]

Comment: It sounds like a fairly straightforward case of attaching a listener to each of the accounts of the user (see the docs for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) or [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)). Unless you have users with hundreds of accounts, this will scale totally fine. Unless you can make your question more concrete, the best advice I can offer is to start building the app and report back if you have a problem.

Comment: @frank: so you suggest to continue with the original design and attach listeners to each account element under "user" sub-tree? I have one concern in that: How should I update the balance? Shall I write a custom logic to update the same under "accounts" sub-tree first and then find out under what all users it is duplicated and update those sub-trees as well. Or shall I not duplicate the balance at all and just update the "accounts" sub-tree? Moreover, as the app scales, a user may have 100's of accounts (directly/indirectly). So, I am not sure if having those many listeners is a good idea.